# Json String Deserilize

Tags: java, json

I called eFinans e-Archive service. faturaOlustur method expects me a json string. I created an variable and assing json string value and giving input parameter. Input parameter expects me String. But variable side expects me only string. I can't solve a solution that problem. Please examine and give me a clue please.

```
public static void eArsivConnectorClient(){
    
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";
    String endPointUrl = "https://earsivtest.efinans.com.tr:443/earsiv/ws/EarsivWebService";
    
    try{        
        EarsivWebService_Service earsivService = new EarsivWebService_Service(new URL (endPointUrl + "?wsdl"));
        earsivService.setHandlerResolver(new SoapHandlerResolver(username, password));
        
        EarsivWebService earsivPort = earsivService.getEarsivWebServicePort();
        WSBindingProvider bindingProvider = (WSBindingProvider) earsivPort;
        bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endPointUrl);
      
        try
        {
            
            EarsivServiceResult srvResult = new EarsivServiceResult();
            Holder<Belge> output = null;

            
            String[] input = new String[]{"vkn","4250566851", "sube","DFLT1", "kasa","DFLT1", 
             "islemId","12232", "erpKodu","ERP1"};**
            
            
            Belge fatura = new Belge();
        
            fatura.setBelgeFormati(BelgeFormatiEnum.UBL);
            
            Path path = Paths.get("C:\\RNK2022000002605.xml");
            byte[] value = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            fatura.setBelgeIcerigi(value);
            EarsivServiceResult arsivBelge = earsivPort.faturaOlustur(input, fatura , output);
            System.out.println(arsivBelge.getResultCode());
          
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
    }catch(Throwable t){
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it Java? Add tag.

Comment: yes, It is Java

Comment: You need to parse the JSON response first. Some libs mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: Hello, I handled that problem. I need another help about json string from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73959212/assigning-input-to-json-string link.